# Перенести текст из файла в матрицу на с++

Tags: c++, файлы

Как перенести текст (по одному слову) в вектор такого вида `vector<vector<string>>`?
Допустим, что в файле хранится вот такой вот текст:

> А !!! Привет
>   жжжж Жук

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
vector<vector<string>> vv;    
while (getline(file, s) {
     vector<string> v;
     istringstream stream(s);
     while (stream >> s) {
          v.push_back(s);
     }
     vv.push_back(v);
}
```